# How to Select hidden input tag with name in b/w the form tag in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to select the hidden box with jquery.

What i did.

In a web page number of forms exists. I want to select the individual form and its in b/w hidden box with jquery. my Javascript code is:

```
function replace_val(clickval)
 {
    var id = $(clickval).attr('id');
    var valuer = $(clickval).attr('value');
    var formid = $("statictext"+id).val();
    $('input[type=hidden][name="packagesale"]').val(valuer);
    $('input[type=hidden][name="pre_post"]').val('Postpaid');
    alert(formid >'input[type=hidden][name="packagesale"]').val());
 }
```

My HTML Code where this function call.

```
<input style="width:85px;" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="replace_val(this);" type="button" id="<?php echo $sno;?>" value="<?php echo $value;"/>
```

I think something is wrong in my alert box code....

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is wrong inside the `alert()`. You should use:

```
function replace_val(clickval)
{
    var id = $(clickval).attr('id'),
        valuer = $(clickval).attr('value'),
        formid = $("#statictext"+id);

    $('input[type=hidden][name="packagesale"]').val(valuer);
    $('input[type=hidden][name="pre_post"]').val('Postpaid');

    alert(formid.children('input[type="hidden"][name="packagesale"]').val());
}
```

Comment: Please put together a jsFiddle. Trying to debug code by guesswork is never a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

you also have error on line

```
 var formid = $("statictext"+id).val();
```

will be

```
var formid = $("#statictext"+id).val();
//or
var formid = $(".statictext"+id).val();// if using class
```

Don't over use jQuery if possible try in pure javascript only

```
    var id = clickval.id;
    var valuer = clickval.value;
```